# rustembedded/cross- can't override linux image

Tags: docker, rust, cross-compiling

I'm attempting to use [rustembedded/cross](https://github.com/rust-embedded/cross) to cross compile to linux but I need to override the default image since I need clang and the default image doesn't provide that.

According to their [documentation](https://github.com/rust-embedded/cross#custom-docker-images), you can provide a dockerfile and a configuration file to accomplish this.

This led me to having a docker file of:

```
FROM rustembedded/cross:x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

RUN dpkg --add-architecture x86_64 && apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends \
    libclang-dev \
    clang
```

and a Cross.toml configuration file of:

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
image = "linux:v2"
```

Then, when I build this image with `docker build -f ./Dockerfile.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -t linux:v2 .`, it gives me an error saying that `dkpg` can't be found. Even if I remove that part it tells me that `apt-get` can't be found.

I can access the shell of the container that it extends, `rustembedded/cross:x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`, in docker desktop and if I run `dpkg`, it shows me the help command. This is confusing since my image extends from it but it doesn't know about `dkpg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rustembedded/cross:x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` is based on `centos`, not `ubuntu`, see its [Dockerfile](https://github.com/rust-embedded/cross/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu):

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

COPY linux-image.sh /
RUN /linux-image.sh x86_64

FROM centos:7
```

It use multistage build, the last os is `centos:7`.

You could also confirm it with next:

```
$ docker run --rm -it rustembedded/cross:x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

I don't know how you get `dpkg` with manual run, definitely something wrong with your steps. But the package system in `centos` is `yum`, you should find same ways using `yum` for your package install.

```
$ docker run --rm -it rustembedded/cross:x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu yum version
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Repodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast
Installed: 7/x86_64                                                                                              213:96cbf4a3c83d0362309d530d515684dce3f40f63
Group-Installed: yum                                                                                              14:302aa408884b4b89361d6bb1c41ceac40665f80e
version
```